# Setting up default audio device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 18.04, alsa, headphones

How can I define the default audio device?

In ubuntu settings, I configure speakers as default device but after system restart it turns back to headphones. In this particular case, I'm using headphones Logitech G430 + Speakers.

I thought pulseaudio will helps, I've installed it and set up speakers as default device, it shows in pulse audio speakers as default but in system configuration as usually headphones leads and controls sound.

*NOTE: It is possible to reproduce this in a complete different setup.*

Comment: I have the same problem. It is very annoying